# Continue playing audio from the time where it was stopped

Tags: android, audio, android-sqlite

I am building an audio player where user can select a song which he wants to listen from a ListView. After he clicks on a song, audio player starts playing that song.

Audio files are not stored locally, they are fetched from some online audio library. After user opens a list of songs, he receives a lot of urls who look like this:

```
http://audiolibrary.com/user/1/77.mp3
http://audiolibrary.com/user/1/567.mp3
http://audiolibrary.com/user/1/34.mp3
```

Each song is identified with unique id as you can see. It's easy to temp download that song and play audio and that is working fine. The thing I want to accomplish is something like this:

1. User clicks on a song1 in list view and song1 starts playing
2. In the middle of the reproduction, user decides he had enough of song1 and switches to song2
3. He closes the app while song2 is still not finished
4. Next time when he opens an app, if he clicks on song1 or song2, reproduction starts from the place where he stopped listening for the song1 or song2

How to efficiently accomplish something like that on Android? Should I create an `SQLite` database for this situation, use `SharedPreferences` or something else? How do you usually handle similar situations?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the time he pressed pause at in a permanent fashion.  The options for this are database, shared preference, web service or file.  Each has pros and cons.

Database pros:  easily extensible with other information if needed, no difficult parsing code

Database cons:  lots of setup code for what's a fairly simple amount of data, additional dependencies on 3rd party code

Shared preference pros:  minimal code to setup and use

Shared preference cons:  not really meant for dynamic string names, slow to parse and performance will degrade as the number of strings decrease, not easily capable of storing additional data.

webservice pros:  would be available across devices/platforms

webservice cons:  requires a server and the most code to do, requires an internet connection

custom file format pros:  absolutely optimized for your needs, easily extensible if you design the format well

custom file format cons: all custom code and you'll have to write all of it.

Pick the one that weighs out the best for you.